# Is backbuffer state preserved (from previous draws) after swapbuffers()?

Tags: opengl

Imagine a situation where:

1. I use double buffering
2. I can optimize my drawing code by not calling `glClear()`, if I assume the backbuffer is in the same state as I left it two `swapBuffers()` ago.

Can I rely on this assumption?

Comment: Disclaimer: I had a hard time trying to find an answer of this question, but I think I finally have the correct one. I'll post my own answer in few days if no one does.

Comment: How could you optimize it? Anyway, it would be micro-optimization and is probably not worth the maintenance overhead.

Comment: @NicoSchertler This is an hypothetical situation, the answer is useful to know. The situation did not occur to me personally, but I needed this answer to answer somebody else's question. Anyway, after even more searching to refine the answer I would have provided, I've finally found that there is a [duplicate](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7316/what-is-the-contents-of-the-buffer-after-a-call-to-glswapbuffers) on gamedev.SE, with a very nice answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The backbuffer contents are undefined after a buffer swap.

> Can I rely on this assumption?

No

Comment: I will certainly not downvote since it is *almost* correct, but it is in fact a wrong answer. The real answer is: it is platform dependent. OpenGL doesn't specify any `swapBuffers()` method, the platform (window management) does. Most of platform would you give an "undefined" backbuffer, but some will give you what was in the frontbuffer.

Comment: @Boris: This is exactly what I wrote: The content of the back buffer after a buffer swap is not defined by the OpenGL specification. It is *undefined*. OpenGL however does define that there is such a thing as double buffering (and even quad buffer stereo). I don't see where writing that the contents are undefined is wrong.

Comment: Well... I do see your point (undefined in the point of view of OpenGL), but still philosophically disagree if I want to be picky ;-) My current understanding is: OpenGL does define the four front/back-left/right buffers, but does not define `swapBuffer()` itself. Hence, the voluntary ill-posed question "does swapping preserve the buffers" doesn't have the answer "no". The correct answer to me is: "The question is ill-posed. Swapping is not part of OpenGL, but are specific platform-provided methods and have different behaviours". Does that make sense, or am I completely wrong?

Comment: @Boris: I answered "no" to your sub question if assuming that swapping the buffers would preserve back buffer contents was safe. I did not answer "no" regarding the contents of the back buffer after a swap. Just that the assumption is not safe and you can't rely on it. And yes, some platforms may specify the behaviour. But to my knowledge there is no single platform that defines the contents of the back buffer after a swap. In fact the behaviour depends on the exact circumstances at runtime (number of windows, open, pointers swapped, or full bitblit performed, etc.) on all platforms I know.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I still disagree with the first part of your answer. I feel that saying that "The backbuffer contents are undefined after a buffer swap." is slightly incorrect, the only correct way to phrase it to me is "a -buffer swap- is undefined, so the question as is do not have an answer" (and then develop, proposing a real question, blah blah). I still accept your answer since this is the practical useful answer someone might look for, and if they are actually as picky as me (poor guys), they can read the comments and get the whole picture.

Comment: @Boris: If you really want to go that length, well, indeed OpenGL does not specify a buffer swap operation. It just defines that there *might* be a back buffer. However the same people who maintain the OpenGL specification also maintain the X11 OpenGL specification GLX. And in that document it is stated `For drawables that are double buffered, the contents of the back buffer can be made
potentially visible (…) by calling glXSwapBuffers(…) The contents of the back buffer then become undefined.` And it's noteworthy that OpenGL and GLX specifications used to stand side-by-side.

Comment: @Boris: Also GLX is kind of the prototype for all the other OpenGL platform dependent APIs out there.

Comment: Ok, thank you for this additional information, the whole discussion was very instructive.